# Total costs as function of labor and quantity

Tags: labor-economics, cost, capital-returns

If I have wage $w = 200$ and rental rate $r = 3050$ on short run, I can assume that $K=1$ and then get the total costs $TC = rK+wL = 3050 + 200L$.

Isn't it correct?

But what if I also have a cost of $400$ on each sold unit. Then my costs will be function of both labor $L$ and quantity $Q$.

Comment: Without the production function it is not possible to answer this question.